# Angular CLI - create a new project choosing Angular2 version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Good morning,
I'm trying to use Angular CLI to start a project in Angular 2 and not in Angular 4, I mean I would like to use version 2.4.10 for example.
There are any way to create it using Angular CLI, can't find which parameters I need to use or if it's possible, I would apreciate any help, Googling I haven't found anything.

I mean, if I type ng new myProject, this project is create in Angular4.

Thank you very much

Comment: what do you mean by "in Angular2 and not in Angular2" ?

Comment: @Arashbahreini just edited, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular-cli v1.0.0 [uses angular ^4.0.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.0/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/package.json#L15-L22) and there is no option to change it.

But it seems like v1.0.0-rc.4 [uses ^2.4.0 by default](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.0-rc.4/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/package.json#L15-L22). And it seems there is an option `ng new <name> --ng4` to use angular4.

Btw ^4.0.0 is backward compatible with 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an earlier version of Angular in a project created using the latest version of the CLI, the after creation is complete you'll have to change the `@angular` versions in the `package.json` to what you need, and run `npm install` for that project.

Note: If you go back to 2.4.10, then make sure the `@angular/router` version you use is 3.4.10.

You can still use the CLI to generate code, and you shouldn't see any insurmountable issues, if you see any at all.

The latest version of the CLI only supports creating new projects with ng4, and newer. What you do with the code after that is entirely up to you.